# MXNet package installation failure in R

Tags: r, ubuntu, package, mxnet, rscript

I have been having issues trying to install **MXNet** in R. I am running the 3.6.1 version of R for which it prompts me saying

```
package ‘mxnet’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)
```

From this I've been advised to try install the package by using these R commands:

```
cran <- getOption("repos")
cran["dmlc"] <- "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/apache-mxnet/R/CRAN/"
options(repos = cran)
install.packages("mxnet",dependencies = T)
library(mxnet)
```

Which then proceed to give me an **error** when downloading the package as followed:

```
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mxnet-r/src/contrib/mxnet_0.10.1.tar.gz'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mxnet-r/src/contrib/mxnet_0.10.1.tar.gz'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  cannot open URL 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mxnet-r/src/contrib/mxnet_0.10.1.tar.gz': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :
  download of package ‘mxnet’ failed
```

I have even tried to follow the [Install MXNet for R guide](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/versions/0.11.0/get_started/ubuntu_setup.html) found on their website but to no luck keep running into errors.

**Error after following [this guide](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781787121089/1/ch01lvl1sec13/installing-mxnet-in-r)**

```
thomas@ThomasUbuntu:~/mxnet$ make -j$(nproc)
Makefile:230: "USE_LAPACK disabled because libraries were not found"
INFO: nvcc was not found on your path
INFO: Using /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc as nvcc path
Running CUDA_ARCH:  
cd /home/thomas/mxnet/3rdparty/dmlc-core; make libdmlc.a USE_SSE=1 config=/home/thomas/mxnet/config.mk; cd /home/thomas/mxnet
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/thomas/mxnet/3rdparty/dmlc-core'
make[1]: 'libdmlc.a' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/thomas/mxnet/3rdparty/dmlc-core'
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -std=c++11 -Xcompiler -D_FORCE_INLINES -O3 -ccbin g++    -Xcompiler "-DMSHADOW_FORCE_STREAM -Wall -Wsign-compare -O3 -DNDEBUG=1 -I/home/thomas/mxnet/3rdparty/mshadow/ -I/home/thomas/mxnet/3rdparty/dmlc-core/include -fPIC -I/home/thomas/mxnet/3rdparty/tvm/nnvm/include -I/home/thomas/mxnet/3rdparty/dlpack/include -I/home/thomas/mxnet/3rdparty/tvm/include -Iinclude -funroll-loops -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -msse3 -mf16c -I/usr/local/cuda/include -DMSHADOW_USE_CBLAS=1 -DMSHADOW_USE_MKL=0 -I/home/thomas/mxnet/3rdparty/mkldnn/build/install/include -DMSHADOW_RABIT_PS=0 -DMSHADOW_DIST_PS=0 -DMSHADOW_USE_PASCAL=0 -DMXNET_USE_MKLDNN=1 -DUSE_MKL=1 -I/home/thomas/mxnet/src/operator/nn/mkldnn/ -I/home/thomas/mxnet/3rdparty/mkldnn/build/install/include -DMXNET_USE_OPENCV=1 -I/usr/include/opencv -fopenmp -DMXNET_USE_OPENMP=1 -DMXNET_USE_OPERATOR_TUNING=1 -DMSHADOW_INT64_TENSOR_SIZE=0 -DMSHADOW_USE_CUDNN=1 -DMXNET_USE_BLAS_OPEN=1 -fno-builtin-malloc -fno-builtin-calloc -fno-builtin-realloc -fno-builtin-free -DUSE_JEMALLOC  -I/home/thomas/mxnet/3rdparty/nvidia_cub -DMXNET_ENABLE_CUDA_RTC=1 -Ipath-to-nccl-installation-folder/include -DMXNET_USE_NCCL=1 -DMXNET_USE_LIBJPEG_TURBO=0" --generate-dependencies -MT build/src/operator/numpy/random/np_uniform_op_gpu.o src/operator/numpy/random/np_uniform_op.cu >build/src/operator/numpy/random/np_uniform_op_gpu.d
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc: not found
Makefile:560: recipe for target 'build/src/operator/numpy/random/np_uniform_op_gpu.o' failed
make: *** [build/src/operator/numpy/random/np_uniform_op_gpu.o] Error 127
```

Answer (score 0):

Last time I solved this error by following [this guide](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781787121089/1/ch01lvl1sec13/installing-mxnet-in-r) (it has some tricks to help installing it on `Ubuntu 16.04+`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still no luck, getting a different error now when running the ```make -j$(nproc)``` command